# How to remove whitespace and comments from a text file?

Tags: python, lexical-analysis

I want to read a text file that contains Python source code and remove comments and extra whitespace from it.

#### file.txt (source code file)

```
#Pythonprogramtofindthefactorialofanumberprovidedbytheuser.

num= 7


factorial=1

ifnum<0:
    print("Sorry,factorialdoesnotexistfornegativenumbers")
elifn um==0:
    print("Thefactorialof0is1")
else:
    foriinrange(1,num+1):
    factorial=factorial*i
    print("Thefactorialof", num," is", factorial)
```

I have tried reading the file and using a list comprehension to filter the lines, but it is not working to remove comments and some whitespace is being removed that I want to keep.

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    
lines = [line.replace(' ', '') for line in lines]
    
with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: What is your actual question? This is currently only a problem statement, what *specific* problem do you need help with?

Comment: I suggest taking look at built-in module [fileinput](https://pymotw.com/3/fileinput/) which is useful when you have to alter text file line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

To remove blank lines and trailing whitespace as well as comments, you could use:

```
import re

with open("file.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line:
            if not re.match(r'\s*#', line):
                file.write(line)
```

#### Output

```
num= 7
factorial=1
ifnum<0:
    print("Sorry,factorialdoesnotexistfornegativenumbers")
elifn um==0:
    print("Thefactorialof0is1")
else:
    foriinrange(1,num+1):
    factorial=factorial*i
    print("Thefactorialof", num," is", factorial)
```